# Clicking a submit button won't refresh the mysql stuff

Tags: php

Sorry if my question seems weird, not sure about how to explain it. Here's an example of what my code is looking for :

```
// SUBMIT FORM
echo '<form action="" method="POST"> 
<input type="submit" value="Stuff" name="Things"/> 
</form>';

// DO THINGS IN MYSQL WHEN CLICKED ON
if (isset($_POST['Things'])) {

    $query= $db->prepare('DELETE item_id FROM users WHERE (player_id=:id)');
    $query->bindParam(':id', $data['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();

}
```

Now, Imagine I had an image linked to the item_id in the page, for instance :

```
foreach ($img in $data['item_id']) { // Show IMG }
```

(This is an example, I may have made some mistakes while writing this but you need to focus on the idea and not the code)

What I would like to do is to make the image (or some text, or some button, or many elements..) when I press the submit button. Because what I have to do right now is making something like this :

```
    if (isset($_POST['Things'])) {

        $query= $db->prepare('DELETE item_id FROM users WHERE (player_id=:id)');
        $query->bindParam(':id', $data['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();

        header("Refresh:0");
        exit();

   }
```

And submiting already "refresh" the page, so doing this lead in a weird double-page refresh.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Ok, so you are submitting a form, so where does $data['id'] appear from?

Comment: Ugh, it's from somewhere in my code, upper.

Comment: you don't need to refresh. Just put the php code __above__ the html, (and remove the `exit`) so that it's deleted before it's grabbed again for display. (I suppose you have a select somewhere above to get the items to be displayed)